# Configure root login bucket for an s3 user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to configure a policy/permission for a specific s3 user so they will login to a particular sub folder under a bucket.

I've got a bucket location here: **s3://foo.s3.amazonaws.com** and underneath is a sub-folder called: 'error' which I want the user to login to by default. So the full path would be: **s3://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/error/**

Is there way for me to configure a a policy/permission so I can have the specific user login into the "error" sub folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a policy and associate it with that user.

`

> `{
>    "Version":"2012-10-17",
>    "Statement": [
>      {
>        "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
>        "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
>        "Effect": "Allow",
>        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
>      },
>     {
>        "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
>        "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
>        "Effect": "Allow",
>        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::foo"],
>        "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","error/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
>       },
>      {
>        "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
>        "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
>        "Effect": "Allow",
>        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::foo"],
>        "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["error/*"]}}
>      },
>      {
>        "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
>        "Effect": "Allow",
>        "Action": ["s3:*"],
>        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::foo/error/*"]
>      }
>    ]
>   }`

Check [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) for more details.